# WPF ListBox and large amound of data

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need to display a large amount of data (thousands of items) in a ListBox however it takes some times and the UI is not responsive until the whole items are displayed in the ListBox.

The ItemsSource of the ListBox is bound the an CollectionView.

I know the benefit of using the VirtualizingStackPanel but I insist to use a WrapPanel.

I've searched over the internet and found some VirtualizedWrapPanels but they have the same issue which is they don't allow the VirtualizingWrapPanel to grow to whatever size it likes and I have to set both Width and Height for them.

Now I need to know what other options are out there for me to do the job? What can I do so that the ListBox loads and displays this large amount quickly.

Please let me know if I haven't explained m
y issue clearly.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

This is the relevant code

```
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            if (_items == value)
                return;

            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Items);
        }
    }
```

I instantiate the ObservableColelction in the LoadData method of the ViewModel

```
   _items = _service.Select();
```

and the CollectionView is instantiated in this way

```
    ICollectionView cv = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Items }.View;
```

and the xaml code of the ListBox

```
            <ListBox
                x:Name="Items"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"
                Padding="10,10,10,10"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="480" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            </ListBox>
```

Comment: **Post the relevant code.**

Comment: [`VirtualizingWrapPanel`](http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I updated the post with the relevant code @HighCodr

Comment: I have used the VirtualizingWrapPanel @Sinatr however it returns an exception "should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is applicable or you are looking for this, however virtualizing the data   is one more solution you can look into. there are some very good posts describing this. these 2 blog/post seems to be very good. Please have a look Here[[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization%5d) and here[[http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.U7a6OvldV1F]](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.U7a6OvldV1F%5d).